# Error :Use of 'self' in property access 'content' before self.init initializes self

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've seen all the problems with keyword `Use of 'self' in property`
but still couldn't solve it. I just started learning swift 3.01 and my Xcode version is 8.2. Please help me!

I was changing [the app Apple provided](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1).

I want to create a `textView` so users can type text and store it.
While I was changing the `Meal.swift`, I got the error:
`Error :Use of 'self' in property access 'content' before self.init initializes self` just at the end of the code:

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {

  //MARK: Properties
  var name: String
  var photo: UIImage?
  var content: String    

  //MARK: Archiving Paths
  static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
  static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")

  //MARK: Types
  struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let photo = "photo"
    static let content = "content"
  }

  //MARK: Initialization
  init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, content: String) {
    // The name must not be empty
    guard !name.isEmpty else {
      return nil
    }

    // The content must not be empty
    guard !content.isEmpty else {
      return nil
    }

    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.name = name
    self.photo = photo
    self.content = content
  }

  //MARK: NSCoding
  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
    aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
    aCoder.encode(content, forKey: PropertyKey.content) 
  }

  required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
      os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Meal object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
      return nil
    }

    // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, photo: photo, content: content)// Error happened to here by this : Error :Use of 'self' in property access 'content' before self.init initializes self
  }
}
```

Please help me to find up the what's wrong in there, Best regard!

Comment: One problem at least is that your `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` refers to `content` without initialising it. Did you mean to have a local value to pass to the designated init, because the compiler thinks you are referring to `self.content`...

Comment: Thank you for your response and change my mistakes in English grammar.
I probably know about it .

Answer (score 2):

You have to decode `content`, too

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as! String

    // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage

    let content = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.content) as! String
    // Must call designated initializer.        
    self.init(name: name, photo: photo, content: content)
}
```

By the way: `guard`ing values in `encode`/`decode` methods reveals developer / design errors. Nobody else but the application can create those objects and you are supposed to know that the value does exist. You must not `guard` to catch runtime errors which should actually never occur.

Comment: It's work about I got another problem that App can running but I can't let  texts in textView stored.
I know the problem probably can fixed by NSUserDefault but I really can't understand how to use it. Can you tell me or tellmy where I can find the way to use? Thank's a lot!

Comment: Sorry, there is no text view related to your code. Ask a new question providing more information and what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem add `let content = content.text` in `MealViewController` 's `func prepare`

It's totally looks like that :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    // Configure the destination view controller only when the save button is pressed.
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }

    let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    let photo = photoImageView.image
    let content = content.text // Add this new code.

    // Set the meal to be passed to MealTableViewController after the unwind segue.
    meal = Meal(name: name, photo: photo, content: content!)

}
```

Just give everyone to be a referance. Hope you will enjoy.